# "often monitors, even censors, of what newspapers local postal patrons would read and what mail they would receive"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Hence not only were local postmasters well informed on local reading habits, they were privy to much of the news locally in circulation and **often monitors, even censors, of what newspapers local postal patrons would read and what mail they would receive**. The post was not a secure channel. ([source](https://press.uchicago.edu/Misc/Chicago/662764.html))

Since "and" is a conjunction, I think what goes after it should be a complete sentence.
And "of what ..." just confuses me.

Comment: I am really glad to see that you've been an active new poster on ELL. Welcome to ELL. Two things you might want to pay attention to: 1. Please use more specific titles. Some of your titles are way too generic to be useful and searchable. For example "The understanding of a sentence" and "The usage of gerund" should be changed to something more specific about the things you are asking about. 2. Please always include a source when you can.

Comment: It would be clearer if changed to "...in circulation and **were** often monitors..." The way it is now made me think at first that it was a mistake and should have been "monitored, even censored." Just a bit of a stumble that forced a slower reading, not actually an error though.

Comment: @Justin Yeah, I stumbled on that part too. I think it'd be less of a stumbling block read out loud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with how "and" is used here.

> they were privy to much of the news locally in circulation *and* often monitors, even censors, of what newspapers local postal patrons would read *and* what mail they would receive.

The first "and" coordinates the two halves of the complement of "were". The words "they were" could optionally be repeated after the first "and" without changing the meaning.

The second "and" coordinates two phrases expressing what was being monitored.

You can be a monitor *of* something, or a censor *of* something. These officials were monitors of what newspapers people were reading. They were also monitors of what mail they received. They were monitors and even censors of these things.